# Как лучше использовать анимацию смерти в Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Посоветуйте как правильно сделать смерть врага, мне нужно чтобы была анимация, после чего объект удалялся со сцены. У меня есть состояние врага, я думал просто отключать его, но выходят очень много ошибок из-за этого. Не судите строго, сам новичок.

Вот код класса врага

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Player _player;
    [SerializeField] private int _health;
    private Animator _animator;
    public Player Target => _player;
    public int EHealth => _health;
    public void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        _health -= damage;
        if (_health <= 0)
        {
            _animator.SetTrigger("Death");
            //Destroy(gameObject, 7);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс состояние врага

```
public class EnemyStateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private State _firstState;

    private Player _target;
    private State _currentState;
    private Enemy _enemy;

    public State Current => _currentState;

    private void Start()
    {
        _target = GetComponent<Enemy>().Target;
        Reset(_firstState);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (_currentState == null)
            return;

        var nextState = _currentState.GetNextState();
        if(nextState != null)
        {
            Transit(nextState);
        }
    }
    private void Reset(State startState)
    {
        _currentState = startState;
        if (_currentState != null)
        {
            _currentState.Enter(_target);
        }
    }

    private void Transit(State nextState)
    {

        if (_currentState != null)
            _currentState.ExitState();

        _currentState = nextState;

        if (_currentState != null)
            _currentState.Enter(_target);
    }
}
```

Вот код состояния

```
public abstract class State : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Transition> _transition;

    protected Player Target { get; set; }
    private Enemy _enemy;

    public void Enter(Player target)
    {
        if(enabled == false)
        {
            Target = target;
            enabled = true;
            foreach (var transition in _transition)
            {
                transition.enabled = true;
                transition.Init(Target);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExitState()
    {
        if (enabled == true)
        {
            foreach (var transition in _transition)
                transition.enabled = false;

            enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public State GetNextState()
    {
        foreach (var transition in _transition)
        {
            if (transition.NeedTransit)
                return transition.TargetState;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Код перехода в другое состояние

```
public abstract class Transition : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private State _targetState;

    protected Player Target { get; private set; }

    public State TargetState => _targetState;

    public bool NeedTransit { get; protected set; }

    public void Init(Player target)
    {
        Target = target;
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        NeedTransit = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для чего именно используется `Transition`? Можете на pastebin залить примеры реализации этого класса?